# Reference for proof of Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, greens-theorem

I'm looking for a rigorous proof of Greens theorem for piecewise smooth jordan curves and would appreciate if someone could link a reference text. The only proof I've seen works for regions which can be bounded by curves $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: a\leq x \leq b,\, \phi(x)\leq y \leq \psi(x)\}$.

The article on wikipedia seems to be lacking several details.

Comment: Is this one sufficient for you https://tinyurl.com/y4js6e36

Comment: Apostol makes some comments in his Calculus, Volume 2

Comment: thanks but neither of them work for more general regions. Some kind of division of the plane into squares should be necessary

Comment: Dividing into squares/rectangles will not suffice. You'll need to use triangles as well, in order to get convergence to the boundary line integral.

Comment: Through rigorous but rather technical corner-smoothing lemmas for piecewise smooth Jordan curves this can be reduced to the case of smooth curves, which one could in turn treat with usual manifold techniques. I suspect  this is quite far from what you are looking for, however.

Comment: I also found this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307713/proof-of-greens-formula-for-rectifiable-jordan-curves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\curl}{\operatorname{curl}} \newcommand{\dm}{\,\operatorname{d}}$
I do not know a reference for the proof of the plane Green’s theorem for piecewise smooth Jordan curves, but I know reference [1] where *this theorem is proved in a simple way for simple rectifiable Jordan curves without any smoothness requirement*.

The key assumptions in [1] are

- a “geometrical” definition of the curl of a vector field as a limit of the value of the circulation integral around the contour of a contracting domain (precisely a $\varepsilon$-side length square $Q_\varepsilon$ centered at the point $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\equiv \Bbb C$)
  $$
  \curl F(x,y)= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\oint\limits_{\partial Q_\varepsilon}F\cdot\dm\ell}{|Q_\varepsilon|}= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\oint\limits_{\partial Q_\varepsilon}F\cdot\dm\ell\label{1}\tag{C}
  $$
  where $| Q_\varepsilon|$ is the area of the vanishing domain
- the hypothesis that the limit in \eqref{1} is uniform.

This allows the Author to prove the theorem in great generality but yet in a relatively simple way.

**Notes**

In reference [1], pp. 703-704, the author briefly reviews other proofs of the theorem found in contemporary literature. In particular he cites Spivak’s *Calculus on manifolds* for a proof of the result for piecewise smooth curves: however, Spivak proves the result in the form of a general Stokes’s theorem for $n$-dimensional manifolds and their (piecewise smooth) boundaries.

**Reference**

[1] Greenlee, W. M., “[On Green’s theorem and Cauchy’s theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1129416470)”, Real Analysis Exchange, 30(2004-2005), No. 2, 703-718, [MR2177428](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2177428), [Zbl 1098.53012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1098.53012).

Comment: This seems very interesting I will have a look at this paper

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment.

I googled a bit but, surprisingly, found no answer exactly matching your natural question. Nevertheless, according to Section 600 (§3 of Chapter XVI) of the book [Fich], Green’s theorem indeed holds for a domain (D) bounded by one or several piecewise-smooth contours. Unfortunately, the author skips some notations, so I had to guess on an exact form of the Green’s theorem he proves. I guess it is following. If the functions $P$, $Q$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$,  and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $(D)$ then
$$\int_{(L)} Pdx+Qdy=\iint_{(D)}\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy.$$
As I understood, the idea of the proof of the general case is to use approximations of the contour $(L)$ by broken lines surrounded by  $(L)$ and by broken lines surrounding $(L)$.

Also I found paper [Zen]. It looks containing a detailed proof of Green’s theorem in the following form.

> Making use of a line integral defined without use of the partition of unity, Green’s theorem is proved in the case of two-dimensional domains with a Lipschitz-continuous boundary for functions belonging to the Sobolev spaces $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\equiv H^{1,p}(\Omega)$, ($1\le p<\infty$).

*References*

[Fich] Grigoriy Fichtenholz, *Differential and Integral Calculus*, v. III, 4-th edition, Moscow: Nauka, 1966, (in Russian). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorii_Fichtenholz) “book was translated, among others, into German, Chinese, and Persian however translation to English language has not been done still”. The guessed proof of Green’s theorems consists of a bit less than four pages: [174](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PWC9.png), [175](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpbZJ.png), [176](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsirF.png), [177](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTkwF.png), and [178](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRJP7.png).

[Zen] Alexander Ženíšek, *[Green's theorem from the viewpoint of applications](http://am.math.cas.cz/full/44/1/am44_1_5.pdf)*, Applications of mathematics **44**:1  (1999), 55–80.

Answer (score 2):

I've yet to come across a rigorous definition of "piecewise smooth". Nečas (1967), *Direct Methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations* (section 3.1.2) proves Green's theorem for sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with *Lipschitz boundary*, which includes the case where $\Omega$ has piecewise $C^\infty$ boundary and the turning angle at each corner is strictly between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. (Lipschitz boundary for $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^2$ means for each $x \in \partial \Omega$, we can define coordinate axes centred at $x$ and choose some open rectangle $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ containing $x$, such that $\partial \Omega \cap V$ can be written as $\{(t,a(t)) : -\epsilon_1<t<\epsilon_1\}$ and $\Omega \cap V$ can be written as $\{(t,s) : -\epsilon_1<t<\epsilon_1,a(t)<s<\epsilon_2\}$ in the new coordinates.)